# How to SVN relocate multiple directories

Tags: bash, svn, shell

I would like to *relocate* multiple checked out SVN directories on my local machine, since our SVN server moved and now has a different IP address. Instead of doing this through a tool like *SmartSVN* or *TortoiseSVN*, I would like to use a script to do the directories in one sweep.

Each directory contains a different working copy - so either a different project or sometimes also a different branch or tag, therefore I can't just do the relocate in the root directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a partial solution on a web page that has disappeared, and also an improved version in the comments, but I wanted to clean it up a bit and provide it here for other people as well

The IP addresses are fictional and need to be adjusted to local settings.

The script iterates over all directories that are managed by SVN and use the old location, then calls the `svn switch` command with the relocate option for each one.

```
#!/bin/bash

OLD_REPO=http://127.0.0.1/svn/
NEW_REPO=http://192.168.0.17/svn/

for dir in `ls -1 */.svn/entries | xargs grep -H -l $OLD_REPO | grep -E -o ^[^\/]+`; do
    echo Switching sandbox $dir from $OLD_REPO to $NEW_REPO;
    
    OLD_ROOT=`svn info $dir | grep ^Repository\ Root | cut -f 3 -d ' '`
    NEW_ROOT=`echo $OLD_ROOT | sed "s|$OLD_REPO|$NEW_REPO|"`
    svn switch --relocate $OLD_ROOT $NEW_ROOT $dir;
done
```

If you also want to change the user while relocating, it's easy to add something like `--username $USERNAME` parameter to the command, and defining the `$USERNAME` at the top of the script.

Comment: The URL of the partial solution seems to link to an empty page... weird.

Comment: Partial solution link now points to an NSFW page!

Answer (score 1):

The solution of @nwinkler was not working on my machine as my version of `grep` does not support the option `-o` (grep 2.4.2 in Msys).

I came up with this other solution which has also the following improvements:

- Support of directory names with spaces
- Support of several *old repository* URLs (e.g. server name and IP address)

Code is much longer and not as elegant, but it does the trick.

The script shall be run from your directories containing your local repositories.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Change separator to support directories with space
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

#URL of new 
NEW_REPO=http://newserver:8080/svn/

#List of potential old repositories
OLD_REPOS[0]=http://oldserver:8080/svn/
OLD_REPOS[1]=http://oldserver.domain.com:8080/svn/
OLD_REPOS[2]=http://127.0.0.1:8080/svn/


for dir in `ls -d1 *`; do
    #Check directory and skip if needed
    if ! [ -d "$dir/.svn" ]; then
        continue;
    fi  
    #Relocate
    OLD_ROOT=`svn info $dir | grep ^Repository\ Root | cut -f 3 -d ' '`
    if [ "`echo $OLD_ROOT | grep $NEW_REPO`" == "$OLD_ROOT" ]; then
        echo "Skipped repository '$dir' (already relocated)";
    else
        for OLD_REPO in ${OLD_REPOS[*]}; do
            NEW_ROOT=`echo $OLD_ROOT | sed "s|$OLD_REPO|$NEW_REPO|"`;
            if [ "$OLD_ROOT" != "$NEW_ROOT" ]; then
                echo "Switching repository '$dir' from $OLD_REPO to $NEW_REPO";
                svn switch --relocate $OLD_ROOT $NEW_ROOT $dir;
                echo "=> done";
                continue 2;
            fi
        done
        echo "Repository '$dir' does not match any old repository identified";
    fi
done

#Restore separator
IFS=$SAVEIFS

#--END--#
```

The approach is slightly different:

- Loop over all the files and directories
- Skip if it is not a SVN repository
- If the local repository matches a URL of old repository, it is relocated